# How to place the cursor on the left side of the text box tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

i wrote bellow code in python 3.6.2 by tkinter,I want the cursor to be on the right side of the text box when click on it.

```
from tkinter import *
class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        super(Application, self).__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_main()
    def create_main(self):
        print("testing")
        self.title = Label(self, text=" Stuck In The Circle ")
        self.title.grid(row=0, column=2)
        self.user_entry_label = Label(self, text="Username: ")
        self.user_entry_label.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.user_entry = Entry(self)                        
        self.user_entry.grid(row=1, column=2)
        self.pass_entry_label = Label(self, text="Password: ")
        self.pass_entry_label.grid(row=2, column=1)
        self.pass_entry = Entry(self)                        
        self.pass_entry.grid(row=2, column=2)
        self.sign_in_butt = Button(self, text="Sign In",command = self.logging_in)#SIGN IN BUTTON
        self.sign_in_butt.grid(row=5, column=2)
    def logging_in(self):
     user_get = self.user_entry.get()
     pass_get = self.pass_entry.get()
root = Tk()
root.title("Stuck in the Circle")
root.geometry("400x100")
app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

how fix it?

Comment: Are you trying to get the widget to insert text from right to left?

Comment: @ Bryan Oakley yes

Comment: Also, your title says "left" but the body of the question says "right"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `justify` option to have the text right-justified:

```
self.user_entry = Entry(self, justify="right")   
self.pass_entry = Entry(self, justify="right")
```

I'm not sure if that's exactly what you're looking for, but it's the only option available. If you want characters to be added to the left, it can be done with custom bindings.

Comment: @naghi: Interesting. It works for me. When I click into one of the entry widgets and start typing, the text appears on the right. Perhaps you can update your question to show that you're using justify but that it has no effect.

Comment: @naghi I just tested your code with Bryan's suggestion and the cursor is on the right side and the text is being typed from the right side.